# Assigning and retrieving an array of strings to a void pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm quite unfamiliar with how pointers work. I'm working with a function that callbacks a function with a `void *` context as an argument.

How would I go about assigning an array of strings to a `void *` and then retrieving them?

```c
char callback_value[2][16];
snprintf(callback_value[0], sizeof(callback_value[0]), "string1");
snprintf(callback_value[1], sizeof(callback_value[1]), "string2");

// pass an array of strings into the void * callback context
void *callback_context = callback_value;


// Illustration only, doesn't work

// retrieve it here
char **retrieved_strings = (char **)callback_context;


printf("%s", retrieved_strings[0]);  // Want "string1"
printf("%s", retrieved_strings[1]);  // Want "string2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(void* arg)
{
  char (*tmp)[16] = arg;
  printf("%s\n%s\n", tmp[0], tmp[1]);
}
int main(void)
{
  char callback_value[2][16] = {"string1", "string2"};
  void *callback_context = callback_value;
  func(callback_context);
  return 0;
}
```

`char**` is not compatible with `char[2][16]`, you have to use a pointer to an array of char `char (*)[16]`.

https://ideone.com/BqgeN6

Comment: So, what you're really saying is that the RHS of `void *callback_context` is not a `char **` but a `char (*)[16]`, and that's why converting the `void *` to `char **` does not work — because `char **` is not the same type as `char (*)[16]`?

Comment: Thanks! What about if the initial `callback_value` is initialised like `char *callback_value[2]` and I wish to pass and access this pointer within the function?